# How do I change the width and height of AlertDialog in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog

How do I change the height and width of my Alert dialog in Kotlin. My alert dialog code looks like this:

```
val loginProgressDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setView(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog, null))
            .setCancelable(false)
            .create()
```

I tried the following but it didn't work

```
    loginProgressDialog.window?.attributes?.width = 100
    loginProgressDialog.window?.attributes?.height = 100
```

If you can link to a post where there is a solution, I'd love that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by using this

```
loginProgressDialog.window?.setLayout(100, 100)
```

You should only use it right after showing the AlertDialog using `loginProgressDialog.show()`

Comment: Thanks man. That worked. Apparently, I did try that before but I called setLayout before I call show.

Comment: @PraantoSamadder you're most welcome, please mark it as the correct answer if it solves the issue!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using custom view for your Alert Dialog, you can set the root layout height and width to wrap content and then add another layout with fixed dimensions inside that. This will make your dialog to inherit the same dimensions as the child view.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:background="@drawable/popup_bg"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```